# Build request URL with variable from another python function

Tags: python, json, function

I am trying to pass a bunch of IDs from one function to another to populate URL params to make another API call in the function.

So far I have the code below but it only passes the last game ID and thus the API call only provides the data for that game.

what is the best way to pass the event_id from the first function to the second so I can make the API call with all the event_id's in the URL?

```
def event_info():

    global event_id

    # US FOOTBALL EVENT INFO API LINK
    link = f'{Base_url}/event/group/{Sport_id}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}'

    # Request data from link as 'str'
    data = requests.get(link).text
    # convert 'str' to Json
    data = json.loads(data)
    # JSON PARSE
    for event_data in data['events']:
        if event_data['group'] == 'NFL' and 'MATCH' in event_data['tags']:
            competition = event_data['group']
            event_id = event_data['id']
            event_name = event_data['name']
            event_start = event_data['start']
            event_status = event_data['state']

            print(competition, event_id, event_name, event_start, event_status)


        # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'unibet_au').document(u'us_football').collection(u'nfl_event_info').document(f'{event_id}')
            doc_ref.set({
                u'competition': competition,
                u'event_id': event_id,
                u'event_name': event_name,
                u'event_start': event_start,
                u'event_status': event_status,
                u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
        })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_info()
```

This code works and prints the data I require to Firestore and returns

```
NFL 1018663095 Denver Broncos - Indianapolis Colts 2022-10-07T00:15:38Z STARTED
NFL 1018644794 Green Bay Packers - New York Giants 2022-10-09T13:30:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663094 Buffalo Bills - Pittsburgh Steelers 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663086 Cleveland Browns - Los Angeles Chargers 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663084 Jacksonville Jaguars - Houston Texans 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663083 Minnesota Vikings - Chicago Bears 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663082 New England Patriots - Detroit Lions 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663081 New Orleans Saints - Seattle Seahawks 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018667663 New York Jets - Miami Dolphins 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663077 Tampa Bay Buccaneers - Atlanta Falcons 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663074 Washington Commanders - Tennessee Titans 2022-10-09T17:00:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663073 Carolina Panthers - San Francisco 49ers 2022-10-09T20:05:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663072 Arizona Cardinals - Philadelphia Eagles 2022-10-09T20:25:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663069 Los Angeles Rams - Dallas Cowboys 2022-10-09T20:25:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663039 Baltimore Ravens - Cincinnati Bengals 2022-10-10T00:20:00Z NOT_STARTED
NFL 1018663037 Kansas City Chiefs - Las Vegas Raiders 2022-10-11T00:15:00Z NOT_STARTED
```

I now need another function which makes an API using those event_id to collect the data for each game. So far I have the below code, but it only uses the last game ID in the list.

```
def match_odds():
    # US FOOTBALL MATCH ODDS API LINK
    url = f'{Base_url}/betoffer/event/{event_id}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}'

    print(url)


    # print(oddsdata)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    match_odds()
```

the URL should look something like this once the IDs are included (I just included 2 game IDs but all will appear in URL)

```
http://xxxx.net/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2/betoffer/event/1018663095,1018644794.json?app_id=21e03bb8&app_key=c0191eaf354cc07bc3769817b8c1acd0&local=en_AU&includeparticipants=false&site=www.xxxx.com.au&type=2&outComeSortBy=lexical&outComeSortDir=desc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `event_id` is only storing each id, then overwriting. You need to collect/store all the ids, and then pass them in. So something like this:

```
def event_info():

    event_ids = [] # <- list of event_ids

    # US FOOTBALL EVENT INFO API LINK
    link = f'{Base_url}/event/group/{Sport_id}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}'

    # Request data from link as 'str'
    data = requests.get(link).text
    # convert 'str' to Json
    data = json.loads(data)
    # JSON PARSE
    for event_data in data['events']:
        if event_data['group'] == 'NFL' and 'MATCH' in event_data['tags']:
            competition = event_data['group']
            event_id = event_data['id']
            event_name = event_data['name']
            event_start = event_data['start']
            event_status = event_data['state']
            
            event_ids.append(str(event_id)) # <-- append each event_id in the list

            print(competition, event_id, event_name, event_start, event_status)


        # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'unibet_au').document(u'us_football').collection(u'nfl_event_info').document(f'{event_id}')
            doc_ref.set({
                u'competition': competition,
                u'event_id': event_id,
                u'event_name': event_name,
                u'event_start': event_start,
                u'event_status': event_status,
                u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
        })
            
        return event_ids # <-- return the list of event_ids

def match_odds(event_ids):   # <-- event_ids list can not be used into the url
    # US FOOTBALL MATCH ODDS API LINK
    idStr = ','.join(event_ids)
    url = f"{Base_url}/betoffer/event/{idStr}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}"

    print(url)


    # print(oddsdata)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_ids = event_info() # <- your list of event_ids from the function
    match_odds(event_ids)  # <-- pass that list into the match_odds function
```

Comment: i couldn't get this to work. still had same issue.

Comment: Theres not much more I can do to help, as I can;t debug your code as I don't have all the part sof the code to run it. The method described above should work if implimented correctly.

Comment: i am getting an error with this part of the code `{','.join(event_ids)}` the error says `'}' `expected and expression expected. when i remove that part of the code and just use `{event_ids}` it works but the formatting of the of url is wrong as you can see here `https://xxxxx.net/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2/betoffer/event/[1018663037, 1018663065, 1018663064, 1018663062, 1018663060, 1018663058, 1018663055, 1018663054, 1018663053, 1018663052, 1018663051, 1018663050, 1018663047, 1018663046, 1018663045].json?app_id=xxxx&app_key=xxx&local=en_AU&site=www.xxxx.com.au`

Comment: made a slight change. try it now